# Dynamic path in Angular2 Router

Tags: dynamic, path, angular, router

I'm looking for a way to receive the current server path as a string in **Angular2**, i.e.

```
http://localhost:3000/my/dynamic/path
```

How can I get: /my/dynamic/path

Answer (score 1):

This should do it the Angular way

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private location:Location) {}    
    repoPath: string;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.repoPath = location.path();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but does not work in my case. what components do you import?

Comment: You need to import `Location`. Do you get an error or does it not return the value you want?

Comment: won't compile. "location.path()" not found on this object. can u provide me with the import line?

Comment: I guess `import { Location } from 'angular2/router';` but I use only Dart and a bit unsure about TS imports.

Answer (score 0):

Found it already:

```
export class AppComponent {
    repoPath: string;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.repoPath = window.location.pathname;
    }
 }
```